# Probelm with pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I'm writing a smaller program to show two values using a function with pointers. It's the same as of the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qG01z8unrU4

```
#include <stdio.h>
int pointers (int i){
    int *p, *q;
    p=&i;
    q=p;
}

 int main(){
    printf("%d %d", pointers(10));
    return 0;
}
```

It should show 10 10. I don't know what to put in the end of function pointers (return what??).

Comment: 1) `pointers()` doesn't return anything, 2) the `printf` template calls for two inputs but you only supply one. There's probably more.

Comment: There's nothing the pointers function can return that would satisfy two `%d` in the format string.

Comment: Functions can only return one value. To return an int add `return *q;`  Change the print to `printf("%d %d", pointers(10), pointers(10));`

Comment: The whole `pointers` function is... pointless (pun intended). Explain in your own terms what you think it is supposed to do.

Comment: _"... It's the same as of the video."_ Not it's not the same, it's only vaguely similar. In the video there is no function that does nothing, no usage of the return value of a function that returns nothing and no wrong usage of printf. Instead of following random tutorials on youtube you should get a book.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> it should show 10 10
> ```

No, it should not. You have plenty undefined behaviours here.

1. Your function has to return `int` value. You do not have return statement. It is undefined behaviour - you cant predict what will be returned
2. Your `printf` requires 2 parameters after the format. You provide only one. It is another UB.

What your program will do is undefined. Everything is possible

As an additional remark your pointers adssigments have no effect and will be optimized out by the compiler.